# codeigniter session userdata from page to page working before but eventually lost on page redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, mariadb

It seems something has gone wrong with my Codeigniter internal. I was able to access session variables from one page to another. But something made me to reinstall PHP and Database (MariaDB).

After the installation my Codeigniter project start losing session data from one page to another page. I did checked if session is actually creating in ci_sessions table; and behold it does; and i can access the session variable from the same page it was set with userdata and not flashdata.

For example

Tt.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tt extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('aa','emi');
        /* if header redirect is commented out and i echo the below
        echo $this->session->userdata('aa'); //will display "emi" */
        /*but if header redirect is not commented out and redirect to Vv.php controller*/
        header("Location: vv"); /*echo $this->session->userdata('aa'); shows nothing in Vv.php controller*/
    }
}
```

Vv.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Vv extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->session->userdata('aa'); //shows nothing
    }
}
```

I haven't set anything else other than uninstalling and installation of  php and database (MariaDB). But before then I can access session variable set in Tt in Vv, and vice versa.

Session setting in config.php is below:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Database Setting in database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
  'dsn' => '',
  'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '<mypassword>',
  'database' => 'appname',
  'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
  'dbprefix' => '',
  'pconnect' => FALSE,
  'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
  'cache_on' => FALSE,
  'cachedir' => '',
  'char_set' => 'utf8',
  'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
  'swap_pre' => '',
  'encrypt' => FALSE,
  'compress' => FALSE,
  'stricton' => FALSE,
  'failover' => array(),
  'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I've tried everything possible but still no luck to get it working back, I don't know if it is MariaDB lock on read. I will be glad if someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: and what appears when you do print_r($this->session->userdata); ?

Comment: print_r($this->session->userdata('aa')) displays "emi" in Tt.php, but when redirected to Vv.php controller print_r($this->session->userdata('aa')) displays nothing

Comment: Load URL helper and try redirecting with `redirect('vv', 'refresh')` if working.

Comment: still doesn't work.

Comment: @amachreetamunoemi What version of CodeIgniter and PHP version are you using?

Comment: @MackieeE i'm using codeigniter-3.1-stable and PHP 7 compiled from source with using php-src git project.

Answer (score 0):

When you set you need to set session single item http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

```
$data = array(
   'aa' => 'emi'
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);

echo $this->session->userdata('aa');
```

Or you can group item

```
$data = array(
  'aa' => 'emi'
);

$this->session->set_userdata('group', $data);
```

Access group data like

```
$something = $this->session->userdata('group');

echo $something['aa'];
```

**Auto load the session library**

Also make sure you have set your session save path if your using CI3 in config.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences

Comment: i've tried the two different ways to set session data as single variables or group, but it's still not working. I did followed the data as they stored in ci_sessions; i found 2 records are stored. the first one is __ci_last_regenerate|i:1471140552; and the second one is __ci_last_regenerate|i:1471140552;something|a:1:{s:2:"aa";s:3:"emi";}, which means it can write session data to ci_sessions but can no more read session data from ci_sessions when page is redirected. i don't know why all of a sudden it stops working just by uninstalling and reinstalling php and database system.

Comment: @amachreetamunoemi can you add your setting for your session from config.php

Comment: Have you auto loaded session library in autoload.php Just a noticed your `'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',` I think should be `'hostname' => 'localhost',` Have you set your database table like http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Comment: did changed 'hostname' => 'localhost' and autoload session in autoload.php as $autoload['libraries'] = array('session'); doing this yields database connection error Message: mysqli::real_connect():(HY000/2002): No such file or directory, Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php, Line Number: 202. when changed back to 'hostname' => '127.0.0.1' the database connection starts working back.

Comment: What about the database as well `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`

Comment: not working. i don't know if the fault is coming from the Database system. I'm using MariaDB. is it that MariaDB is having read lock issue.